# Deploy python deb test project using make-deb and dh-virtualenv

Tags: python, deployment, anaconda, deb

In development I use Anaconda to manage environments. I have not yet developed a python project for production. In this context I have two related questions.

First, which solution incurs lower technical debt: A. Install Anaconda on  production servers; or B. deploy python as deb packages?

Second, what is the simplest structure of python project folders and files to test the functionality of make-deb and dh-virtualenv as described in the last section of Nylas blog article?

Nylas blog (How We Deploy Python Code: Building, packaging & deploying Python using versioned artifacts in Debian packages)

https://www.nylas.com/blog/packaging-deploying-python/

Make-deb:
https://github.com/nylas/make-deb

dh-virtualenv:
https://github.com/spotify/dh-virtualenv

Package Python Application for Linux (Link Added November 2022):
https://opensource.com/article/20/4/package-python-applications-linux

For a test I would only add Requests package to a standard Python 2.7 environment and write one module to download and save a small csv file. Then I would like to test make-deb and dh-virtualenv to deploy to a cloud server or Raspberry pi server. Then I want to run code to verify the download app works as expected on the server. Then I want to further develop the application and test deployment tools using make-deb and dh-virtualenv to see if I can more effectively manage development for production.

Edit: Based on some further research so far it appears Anaconda cannot be made to export a requirements.txt file. It appears the options are to use virtualenv, make-deb, and dh-virtualenv; or to use Anaconda and Miniconda roughly as described in the following blog articles:

https://tdhopper.com/blog/2015/Nov/24/my-python-environment-workflow-with-conda/

https://www.thoughtvector.io/blog/deployment-with-anaconda/